# When is a mybatis session opened if use spring to inject mapper?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

If without spring, a Mybatis Mapper is used like this:

```
try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
    Mapper mapper = session.getMapper(Mapper.class);
    result = mapper.select(...);
}
return result;
```

While using spring, a mapper is used like this:

```
@Inject
private Mapper mapper;

public Response work() {
    result = mapper.select();
    return result;
}
```

My question is when is the session opened?

Answer (score 1):

SqlSession is opened by SqlSessionTemplate provided by mybatis-spring and it is shared on multiple query using Spring Transaction management mechanism.

Note: SqlSessionTemplate manage a proxy object of SqlSession using JDK proxy.